# Copying Existing Sheets in Excel Slows down my VBA code significantly

Tags: vba, excel

I've been building a program to create invoices dependent on the number of clients/owners my company is interacting with. For every one client, we potentially have multiple owners, what we do is create an individual invoice for each owner. My problem is that the code is designed to copy a template sheet and then edit it accordingly, this copying process slows down my code to between 10 and 20 seconds (I have a timer in the code).

Is there any other way I could more efficiently do this? I have an image in the sheet which does not copy over well when I simply try to create a new sheet and then copy/paste from the template sheet. Any other ideas?

Thanks!

Edit:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim t       As Single
t = Timer
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Sheets("Client Invoice Template").Visible = True
Sheets("Client Invoice Template").Visible = True
Sheets("Client Invoice Template").Copy Before:=Sheets(3)
Sheets("Client Invoice Template (2)").Name = "Client Invoice"
Sheets("Client Invoice Template").Visible = False
Sheets("Select").Select Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
MsgBox Timer - t
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you please post your code? We can't really help without knowing what code you have (other than general comments, like add `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` to the start of your Sub).

Comment: Yea sorry, I should've done that. I've included all the tips from here

http://www.cpearson.com/excel/optimize.htm

As I've seen it recommended before. Here is the code for copying

Comment: Dim t As Single    
t = Timer    
Application.ScreenUpdating = False    
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual  

    Sheets("Client Invoice Template").Visible = True    
    Sheets("Client Invoice Template").Visible = True    
    
    Sheets("Client Invoice Template").Copy Before:=Sheets(3)    

    Sheets("Client Invoice Template (2)").Name = "Select"    
    
    Sheets("Owner Invoice Template").Visible = False    
    Sheets("Client Invoice Template").Visible = False    

    Sheets("Select").Select  

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic    
MsgBox Timer - t

Comment: Thanks for the code - I've edited your OP to include it (when including code, it's best to include in the post, not a comment since (as you can see) it tends to crunch it up and is hard to read/follow).

Comment: Thank you! I've been going through the formatting page trying to to figure out how to edit my comment it so it works.

Comment: To clarify - your main issue is that your code above takes too long to run, 20 seconds??

Comment: how about 1) create a new sheet, 2) copy and paste values and formatting from template to new sheet 3) copy the image from the template to the new sheet 4) and set it's top left cell property to fit it where you want.? I suspect the image is slowly down the sheet.copy operation

Comment: @BruceWayne - 3 owners at 20 seconds each = 1 minute for a simple sheet copy operation! Way too long for me ... but maybe I am spoiled :)

Comment: @ScottHoltzman - just from the code, I don't see how it could take that long. Interesting indeed!  Are there any other macros perhaps, such as a `Worksheet_Change` event or something?

Comment: It appears to be a one off thing, and each time the sheet will need to get overwritten, My question why not manipulate the data in the template, print it and then clear it?

Comment: @BruceWayne - I have a strong hunch it's the picture that is causing the slow down. See the test I did in my answer.

Comment: @ScottCraner Unless you mean something other than printing in the most traditional sense (not very up to date on tech lingo), it's because the sheets require further manipulation afterwards. The first step is copying the templates, so that the original menu is hidden, then followed by a new menu to edit the sheets that have been copied (one to owner, one to client, one for taxes).

Comment: @ScottHoltzman The strange thing is that further on, there is a point where ten clients (at two sheets each) need to be copied, but the time still floats around 15-25 seconds, very strange indeed that the increase in the number of sheets doesn't increase the amount of time required linearly.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the method in my comment, I did a test with my own (very simple) template that is shown below for full disclosure:

[image]

### Method 1 (Your Code)

it took **0.09375** seconds to complete.

### EDIT: Method 2 (based on Bruce Wayne's Comment)

it took **.015625** seconds to complete! That is **6xs** as fast!

```
Sub CommandButton3_Click()

Dim t As Single
t = Timer

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
End With

Dim wsT As Worksheet, ws As Worksheet

Set wsT = Sheets("Client Invoice Template")
wsT.Visible = True 'view template

Set ws = Sheets.Add(Before:=Sheets(3)) 'add new sheet

With wsT
     'copy row height and column width
     'row height
     Dim rng as Range
     For each rng in .range("A1:A100")
           ws.Rows(rng.Row).RowHeight = rng.Height
     Next

     'column width
     For each rng in .Range("A1:D1")
          ws.Columns(rng.Column).ColumnWidth = rng.Width
     Next

wsT.Range("A1:D100").Copy 'copy template data (change range accordingly)

With ws
    .Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues 'past values (change range accordingly)
    .Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats 'past formats (change range accordingly)

    .Pictures.Insert("C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\Chrysanthemum.jpg").Select

    With .Shapes("Picture 1")
        .Top = ws.Range("B2").Top 'adjust as needed
        .Left = ws.Range("B2").Left 'adjust as needed
        .Height = 126.72 'adjust as needed
        .Width = 169.2 'adjust as needed
    End With

    .Name = "Client Invoice"

End With

wsT.Visible = False

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

Debug.Print Timer - t

End Sub
```

### Method 3 (Based on My Comment)

it took **0.03125** seconds to complete! That is **3Xs** as fast!

Code is below:

```
Sub CommandButton2_Click()

Dim t As Single
t = Timer

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
End With

Dim wsT As Worksheet, ws As Worksheet

Set wsT = Sheets("Client Invoice Template")
wsT.Visible = True 'view template

Set ws = Sheets.Add(Before:=Sheets(3)) 'add new sheet

wsT.Range("A1:D100").Copy 'copy template data (change range accordingly)

With ws
    .Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues 'past values (change range accordingly)
    .Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats 'past formats (change range accordingly)
End With

wsT.Shapes("Picture 1").Copy 'change to your picture name accordingly

With ws
    .Range("B2").PasteSpecial 'paste to cell (change range accordingly)
    .Name = "Client Invoice" 'rename
End With

wsT.Visible = False

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

Debug.Print Timer - t

End Sub
```

Comment: Not sure if it would speed anything up, but what if you saved the picture to some folder, created the new sheet, then just imported it? ...as I type that, it sounds like it'd take longer, but would the code actually take longer to run?

Comment: kudos @BruceWayne! I tested your idea and it helped make it 6x's faster versus 3x's! Nice idea.

Comment: Woah, I was 95% positive it would have slowed it down, not the complete opposite!  I guess `.Copy` takes up a lot more resources than I realized.

Comment: Wow, thank you guys so much for all this help. I've been sick for the past few days. So I'm sorry I didn't answer sooner, I will post when I can with the results. I just have to extrapolate this over multiple sheets and scenarios.

Thanks again!

Comment: I'm having the same problems as before fellas. What I've done is delete the images from all of my templates because I also have a "Select" Template which will add the proper banner image depending on which is selected anyways, but my compute times are still around ten seconds. My Select template does have multiple Active X controls which might contribute to slowing things down? But even when trying to apply you guys' code, it still wouldn't copy the templates in the proper format, some of the columns and rows are of varying lengths and excel doesn't seem to grasp that.

Comment: Thanks for the insights though guys!

Comment: Also just tried isolating the problem, and removing the Select being copied has no effect on the processing time. I wonder if it has something to do with the formatting itself that slows everything down so much, it seems to be the one unchanged variable, and doing the copying pasting methods like recommended above always seem to ruin the formatting.

Comment: when you say *ruin the formatting* - what do you mean exactly? Is it just the row height and column widths? Excel does not consider that `formatting`. You'd have to set that manually. I have edited the code in Method 2 to do that before the copy and paste of values / formats. Set all the `ActiveX` controls in the `Select` template to `Don't move or size with cells` in the **Format Controls > Properties** and they will not copy over by default (unless you need them too .. in which case you may be stuck with the timing :()

Comment: @ScottHoltzman Yes, the row height and column widths have all been tampered with in the template for various reasons. If those can't be copied over I suppose I am stuck with my poor timing. I'll try your newly edited method 2 and post with results. Thank you!

Comment: Wow, one thing that has changed simply by removing the images from my templates while keeping the old code is that when I do service invoices my compute time has gone down to 0,5 seconds! I'm currently running into a problem with rental invoices because for some reason the code copies and tries to rename twice one of my templates which is causing an error. Figuring that out right now.

Comment: @AlexVanHouten - Also pay attention to my comment about the `ActiveX` controls.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman Ah yes, I did. But I do need to copy over the active X controls. I just wanted to update you guys on what I've discovered. I've found that with my code I get a very manageable average of around 1 second or less since I removed the banners and have them added afterwards. 
What I've found most interesting is that once the banners are set in place each invoice, I have a macro to copy those sheets to create more duplicates for more invoices that can be tweaked (upwards of 10) and the time for those to be copied is only around 0.2 seconds.

Comment: glad you got it @AlexVanHouten! Even if its not fully understandable why the time differences exist now.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman Thank you, just thought you'd be interested by that little tidbit. Thanks again, great first experience asking a question here.